# ESP32 - esp-idf Wifi Scan while mesh connected

Tags: wifi, mesh, esp32, esp-idf

Hi I have multiple ESP connected via wifi-mesh.

I want to perform a Wifi scan while the ESP is mesh connected ( and If I found a specific AP tell to the ESP to connect to it ).

I'm trying to do this: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp ... -mesh.html
At Calling Wi-Fi API paragraph.
But the ESP "sees" only a single AP:

```
uint16_t number = 10;
        wifi_ap_record_t ap_info[10];
        uint16_t ap_count;
        memset(ap_info, 0, sizeof(ap_info));

        wifi_scan_config_t scan_config = {
            .ssid = 0,
            .bssid = 0,
            .channel = 0,
                .show_hidden = true
        };


        //Disable self organized networking
        esp_mesh_set_self_organized(0, 0);

        //Stop any scans already in progress
        esp_wifi_scan_stop();
        //Manually start scan. Will automatically stop when run to completion
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_scan_start(&scan_config, true));
        //Process scan results

        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_scan_get_ap_records(&number, ap_info));
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_scan_get_ap_num(&ap_count));
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Total APs scanned = %u", ap_count);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "SSID : %s\n", ap_info[i].ssid);

        }

        //Re-enable self organized networking if still connected
        esp_mesh_set_self_organized(1, 0);

        //Re-enable self organized networking if non-root and disconnected
        esp_mesh_set_self_organized(1, 1);

        //Re-enable self organized networking if root and disconnected
        esp_mesh_set_self_organized(1, 0);  //Don't select new parent
        esp_mesh_connect();                 //Manually reconnect to router
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please elaborate on "_But the ESP "sees" only an AP:_" - what do you see and what are you expecting to see? Also, you're blindly iterating over 10 scan results when you should be iterating over `ap_count` scan results (up to a maximum of 10). This is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I have many AP ( on 2.4 Ghz ) so, ESP should shows also other SSID.
It shows me only one:

i.e.: These are SSID's of AP: "Ap_A", "Ap_XYZ", "Ap_C"
It shows me only "Ap_A"

Comment: And what does the line `ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Total APs scanned = %u", ap_count);` print?

Comment: it prints  = 1, but there are many Aps

Comment: In order to do wifi scan, it need to be in STATION mode, and be disconnected from the AP. In Arduino, this means calling `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA)`; then `WiFi.disconnect();`, once you done the scan and obtained the scan data, you need to call `WiFi.scanDelete();` to remove the list so that it doesn't capture the old data on future scan.

Comment: I have 2 different behaviour:


1) if the node is root: I got a list of SSID's AP
2) if the node is a child connected to the root: I got only the SSID of the parent